# Is there any way I can rename my soldiers?

Tags: open-xcom

I'm running OpenXcom and wondered if there is any way to having the game automatically rename my soldiers in order to classify them by ability, i.e. high accuracy, strong, and so on.

I think this was available as a patch to the original release of the game, and wondered if there was anything similar available.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be an official patch. There aren't any of those, far as I know.

Comment: @RavenDreamer There are lots of unoffical patches however; today we'd call them mods. I don't know of this one though.

Answer (score 5):

You can just click on a soldiers name in the stats menu to change his/her name.

[image: http://www.mobygames.com/images/shots/l/358315-x-com-ufo-defense-dos-screenshot-soldier-stats-s.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Statstrings](https://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php/Statstrings). Check the built-in **XcomUtil StatStrings** mod as an example you can modify to your will.